# dia2code - how to handle use of stl classes

Tags: uml, dia

I want to use STL classes with dia2code in my diagram. However I'm not sure how to get dia2code to include those files when generating. Is there any way to get it to include them. Perhaps by modifying my diagram. I want to be able to place all updates to my class definitions in the diagram then just run a simple tool to update them.